# GMail API with service account requires cloud account?

Tags: oauth-2.0, gmail-api, google-oauth, service-accounts

What is Google cloud platform account. Is it required for setting up service account and using GMail API for sending emails ?

I have done this setup few months back with my personal free account. It is still working fine.

But now the latest document says, cloud account is mandatory.Could you please clarify me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused on a few points.

In order to access any Google API you need to register your application on [Google Developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) this is sometimes called Google Cloud console or Google API console.   Google has been changing the name a lot lately.

Google Developer console is free you don't need to pay to access this.  Its purpose is to register applications and spawn cloud servers.  You will have to pay for spawning cloud servers and some of the APIs also require that you pay for them (not GMail).

Note: service accounts only work with Gmail when you have a [Google domain account](https://gsuite.google.com/products/admin/) or Google for [work account](https://gsuite.google.com/index.html). Both of which you have to pay for.  You cant access a normal users Gmail account using a service account.